# File upload ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there an obvious reason as to why there is no file being crated in `./data/stockhelper`. The permissions are correct.

```
public function uploadAction()
{

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if($request->isPost()) {

        $files =  $request->getFiles()->toArray();

        $httpadapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
        $filesize  = new \Zend\Validator\File\Size(array('max' => 100000 )); //1KB
        $extension = new \Zend\Validator\File\Extension(array('extension' => array('xlsx')));

        $httpadapter->setValidators(array($filesize, $extension), $files['file']['name']);
        if($httpadapter->isValid()) {
            // We get here.

// move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], sprintf('./data/stockhelper/%s.%s', sha1_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']), 'xlsx')); // <--- this works


            $httpadapter->setDestination('./data/stockhelper');
            if($httpadapter->receive($files['file']['name'])) {
                // We don't get here;
                $newfile = $httpadapter->getFileName();
                var_dump($newfile);
            }


        }
    }


    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this just remaining move uploaded file to destination. `$httpadapter->receive()` just for checking file uploaded or not. It was not purposed for moving uploaded files. You should use `Filter` for this, and call `File\Rename` filter.

```
$httpadapter->setDestination('./data/stockhelper');
$httpadapter->setValidators(array($filesize, $extension), $files['file']['name']);
$httpadapter->addFilter('File\Rename', array('target' => $httpadapter->getDestination() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . sha1_file($files['file']['name']) . '.xls', 'overwrite' => true));

if (!$adapter->receive()) {
    // uploading error
    $messages = $httpadapter->getMessages();
} else {
    $newfile  = $httpadapter->getFileName();
}
```